# SET(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL ...) with ExternalProject Installing Additional Components

Tags: cmake, cpack

I use the [ExtrenalProject](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html) cmake module to add 3rd party or internal dependencies to my build. I then use the [CPack](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/CPack.html) module with components to install only components from the current code base in the following manner.

```
set(CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL
  common-lib
  common-include
  common-depends
)
```

An example of one of these components declared in CMake is:

```
install(TARGETS common
  LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib
  COMPONENT common-lib
)
```

However, other projects added using `add_subdirectory` such as google test or other internal libraries also declare install targets. When I run

```
make package
```

and then list the contents of the `.deb` or `.tar` generated, I see the contents of other components not set in the `CPACK_COMPONENTS_ALL` variable.

What is the proper way to get CMake and CPack to only install the components requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the argument [`EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/add_subdirectory.html) to the end of the `add_subdirectory()` call.  This will essentially disable all of the `include()` calls made in the added subdirectories.